# Remove option to allow trackbacks/pingbacks from post page options

Tags: php, posts, customization, pingbacks

I'm trying to disable all functionality related to pingbacks/trackbacks in WordPress and so far I have this:

```
add_action( 'pre_ping', 'disable_pingback' );

function disable_pingback( &$links ) {
    foreach ( $links as $l => $link ) {
        if ( 0 === strpos( $link, get_option( 'home' ) ) ) {
            unset( $links[ $l ] );
        }
    }
}
```

However when I open up the page options and enable *discussion*, I still see this:

[image]

I found this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103511/1839) (method 2), but it is over 5 years old now and I wasn't sure if totally replacing the whole section was the best way to do things compatibility wise, so I am asking again...

Is there a *cleaner* way to accomplish this?

Comment: Disable the xmlrpc.php if you're not using it anymore. The pingback/trackback will disable too. You can block xmlrpc via Nginx or .htaccess config.

Comment: @HồTrọngLinhÂn I thought of doing that but I read that can block access to things such as WP apps that legitimately need to connect to it remotely.

Comment: Second method is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The WordPress Codex solutions weren't working for me regardless of what parameters I used or the priorities set, probably because my setup is pretty complex or as others have commented. The first chunk of code may work for you but I don't have a default environment at the moment to test. The second chunk of code definitely worked for me. The last chunk of code removes the option from the post's quick edit as well.

You will still need to disable the functionality as you have done.

Wordpress Codex solution, *(hooks into add_meta_boxes so it fires last, but you can use admin_menu or do_meta_boxes instead).*
Documentation [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box)

```
function remove_trackbacks_pingbacks() {

            remove_meta_box('trackbacksdiv', 'post', 'normal');

}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'remove_trackbacks_pingbacks');
```

This may be overkill, but this is what actually worked for me. Note that it will remove the option in the box from displaying everywhere, including pages too. It also allows you to customize the HTML as well just in case you wanted to add a note to tell the user that Pingbacks and Trackbacks have been disabled. *(this may or may not suit your needs, but here it is anyway).* Documentation [Here](https://gist.github.com/eteubert/1327291)

```
    function remove_trackbacks_pingbacks ($post_type, $post) {

    global $wp_meta_boxes, $current_screen;

    # Remove "ping_status" from `commentstatusdiv`:
    $wp_meta_boxes[$current_screen->id]['normal']['core']['commentstatusdiv']['callback'] = function($post) {

        ?>
            <input name="advanced_view" type="hidden" value="1">
            <p class="meta-options">
                <label for="comment_status" class="selectit">
                    <input id="comment_status" name="comment_status" type="checkbox" value="open" <?php checked($post->comment_status, 'open'); ?>> Allow comments?
                </label>
                <?php do_action('post_comment_status_meta_box-options', $post); ?>
            </p>
        <?php

    };

}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'remove_trackbacks_pingbacks', 10, 2);
```

Lastly, since you want to remove the option from your edit screen, I assume you may want to remove from the quick edit screen as well. There are no hooks or classes to hook into that I know of, so a pure jQuery solution is in order. Insert into functions.php

Modified from this solution [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59871/remove-specific-items-from-quick-edit-menu-of-a-custom-post-type)

```
    add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', 'remove_pings_quickedit' );

function remove_pings_quickedit() 
{    

    global $current_screen;
     if( 'edit-post' != $current_screen->id )
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">         
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {           
            $('span:contains("Allow Pings")').each(function (i) {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $('input[name=ping_status]').each(function (i) {
                $(this).remove();
            });
                   });    
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - the `remove_trackbacks_pingbacks` is useful, but the method to get rid of the point of my question is the same as "method 2" in the answer I linked to, not really something I want to do for future code comparability. Thank you for the useful other snippets though.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad remove trackbacksdiv did the trick. I don't have that div id available to target unfortunately, so I had to use method 2 but instead of removing the core commentsstatusdiv and replacing it with a custom meta box, an alternate solution is to just modify the original in the child theme. It should still work in the future should you want to further modify its contents, as long as WordPress doesn't change those core hooks. It does introduce a few extra variables though.

Comment: Simply removing the trackbacksdiv with the first function should be pretty standard and stable though, unless you have a plugin modifying your metabox.

Comment: Hmm yeah. It seems pretty much any way to handle this has it's shortcomings as there really is no official way to handle it unfortunately from what it seems. I'm starting ti think either CSS or JS is the cleanest way to get rid of it even if the targeted ID could change.

Comment: remove_meta_box('trackbacksdiv', 'post', 'normal'); is the official recommendation from the codex, so it's probably the safest bet. It's only a problem if you have extraordinary theme mods.

Comment: Sorry I meant to remove the "trackbacks/pingbacks" portion within the "Discussion" box, `remove_meta_box('trackbacksdiv', 'post', 'normal');` works great, but removes a different meta box altogether :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, AFAIK. It will disable the ability to do trackback/pings. It doesn't remove that option from the screen, as you have noticed.

Not sure how to test that, though. But your code should work to disable the actual process of allowing trackback/ping.

This site *might* test trackback/pings https://tech.wizbangblog.com/ping.php . No experience with it, so YMMV.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the ability is the most important thing, but I guess removing the option to select that would also be nice so users don't go expecting it is supposed to work when they check it.

Comment: I suppose you could use some custom CSS to display:none those fields. Or dig into the source code of that page and find any possible filters to remove the field. Some custom CSS might be easier, although less 'pure'. Also, see the answer on this page: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103502/hide-allow-trackbacks-pingbacks?noredirect=1&lq=1 . Plus the answer to this question might be helpful: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31943/is-there-a-way-to-completely-turn-off-pingbacks-trackbacks?rq=1

Comment: Cheers - I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

The way described in the answer you point to is the easier to understand way using PHP. I agree that from a code stability POV it sucks as you need to make sure that nothing else ever changes in that meta box.

The other way to do it in php is to remove the core metabox, and create one of your own, in which you call the original one aand filter out the relevant output. It is still ugly, and you will have to write a long comment for it explaining the WHY of it, but it is more likely to remain stable than the first way.

Using JS or CSS to hide that checkbox is likely to be a much more stable idea. You are still betting against the ID being changed, but this is probably much less likely to happen and produce a much easier to understand code.

Comment: Some good options to consider, as there really doesn't seem like a proper, completely clean way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the WordPress recommended way of doing it:

```
function remove_post_custom_fields() {
    // Remove Discussion meta box
    remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'post', 'normal');

    // Remove Comments meta box
    remove_meta_box('commentsdiv', 'post', 'normal');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_post_custom_fields');
```

Replace `post` with `page` or with another custom post type if needed.

Relevant codex link:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

Enjoy!

Comment: this is likely not to do what the OP asks for as it most likely removes the comment option as well.

Comment: Well, there are to `remove_meta_box()` calls. He could remove the second one. I have edited my answer and added code comments.

Comment: This removes the whole box including the "comments" part, not just the pingbacks/trackbacks option.

Comment: Remove this line - `remove_meta_box('commentsdiv', 'post', 'normal');` - and it will keep the Comments box.

Comment: as its name implies `remove_meta_box` removes whole of the meta box, not just parts of it.

Comment: @MarkKaplun exactly. And there are 2 meta boxes: `commentstatusdiv` and `commentsdiv`. `commentstatusdiv` is the checkboxes box and `commentsdiv` is the Comments/Activity box.

Comment: the problem is that the OP want to remove just part of the enable comments/pingback meta box, not all of it

Comment: My code, minus the second meta box removal, should do it.

Answer (score -3):

> Please put below code on your theme's `functions.php` file. I hope it will work for you

```
function hide_ping_track() {    
    echo "<style>.meta-options label[for=ping_status], #ping_status{display:none !important;}</style>";      
}
add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'hide_ping_track');
```

Comment: This is not good at all. You shouldn't use CSS to hide these type of things/

Comment: I don't think so .why it's not good can you please describe?

Comment: downvoted as "place some code" without any explanation is just not an answer in the standards of this site. You should improved it and explain what it does at the very least